# What is the meaning of line 2 quoted below?

Tags: solidity

```
import ./ClaimHolder.sol

ClaimHolder public trustedClaimHolder;(//Doubt ?)
function ClaimVerifier(address _trustedClaimHolder) public {

}
```

Comment: They are simply variable and function declarations, with `trustedClaimHolder` being of type `ClaimHolder`

Comment: Also the import syntax is wrong here. The imported file should be in quotes the line should end with semicolon, like `import "./ClaimHolder.sol";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why this is flagged unclear. Question is to help parse a specific line of code.

`Claimholder public trustedClaimHolder;`

This is casting `trustedClaimHolder` as an instance of `Claimholder` and making it public.

`Claimholder` is likely defined in the imported `Claimholder.sol`. It could be a `contract` or a `struct`. Look for

`contract Claimholder {` in which case `trustedClaimHolder` will have the contract methods.

`struct Claimholder {` in which case `trustedClaimHolder` will have the struct members.

Hope it helps.